# PayPal Order PATCH call throws bad request

Tags: java, paypal, microservices, integration, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on a PayPal payment integration using a Java Springboot microservice where in an order is created on PayPal, i'm retrieving the order details from the paypal successfully. Now I want to update the order in the PayPal by adding an attribute invoice_id. But, when the Update Order(PATCH)  is being called, Paypal throws a bad Request.
Doc link : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_capture_request.customized_x_unsupported_3218_order_application_context

```
PATCH https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{{order_Id}}
Request : 
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/invoice_id",
  "value": "123456"
}
```

Error Response: `[{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"1ef2afd17aa1p", "details":[{"field":"/","location":"body","issue":"MALFORMED_R... (421 bytes)]`

Can someone help me on this please.

I tried out multiple things like changing the request body. But, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Docs don't mention the `/@reference_id=='default'` part of your path.  Closest I see is `purchase_units[].invoice_id`.  Wish I could see more of the error.. `MALFORMED_R` what's that :D

Comment: Update your question with the entire error response JSON, and the order creation request + response may also be relevant

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.